# Como criar uma tabela Produtos que possuí diversos preços?

Tags: sqlite, entidade-relacionamento

Alguém saberia como mapear uma tabela Produtos, sendo que o produto possuí diferentes preços para cada tipo de parcela que o cliente escolher. Por exemplo eu criei uma tabela chamada PRECOS e nela existe FK do PRODUTO, mas na hora de criar os laços foreach e popular o datagrid é necessário que cada PRODUTO liste seus diferentes preços. Para deixar mais claro minha pergunta:

Um PRODUTO pode ser parcelado em até 12x e para cada tipo de parcela o valor é diferente, então existem as tabelas:

Tabela PRODUTO

```
PRODUTOID, 
DESCRICAO, 
COR, 
TAMANHO, 
TECNOLOGIA, 
FORNECEDOR, 
IMAGEM_NOME, 
IMAGEM_CAMINHO
```

Tabela PRECOS

```
PRECOID, 
QTD_PARCELAS, 
VALOR, 
PRODUTOID
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar como criar o laço foreach mapeamento os diversos preços referente a diversos produtos, eu agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1):

Cara, você fazer um for ou foreach pegando os produtos e um outro foreach para obter cada preço. Seria isso certo? Tente seguir este exemplo. Abraços

```js
var produtos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    produto: "Produto 1",
    price: 150
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    produto: "Produto 2",
    price: 600
  }
];

var precos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    qtd: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    qtd: 3
  }
];


for(var i = 0; i < produtos.length; i++){
   console.log("Produto: ", produtos[i].produto, " / Preço total: ", produtos[i].price);
   for(var j = 0; j < precos.length; j++){
      console.log("Parcela: ", precos[j].qtd, " vezes / Preço: ", produtos[i].price / precos[j].qtd, " R$");
   }
}
```